# Different Logical Subnet on same Physical network cause Linux Connectivity Issues

Tags: linux, networking, subnet

We have two Linux CentOS hosts, A and B.

```
A = 19x.2xx.6.4 (/24)
B = 19x.2xx.7.4 (/24)
```

Both these hosts are on the same physical switch. The reason why they are on different logical networks is because in the future they will be on separate physical networks.

A can ping B, and from A you can SSH to B.

You can also `TRACEROUTE` from A to B, in this case it goes through router C (19x.1x.8.1).

You cannot NMAP from A to B and various other important network utilities fail when connecting from A to B. The general effect is the same as a time-out.

The router in has aliases on the Cisco as such:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 19x.2xx.6.1 255.255.255.0 secondary
 ip address 19x.2xx.7.1 255.255.255.0 secondary
 ip address 19x.1x.8.1 255.255.255.192
```

I am at a loss how to fix this problem. Please assist.

Comment: You can ping, SSH and traceroute from A to B. That is very clearly not a connectivity problem. The problem is that there's a firewall on B that is preventing other types of connections from A.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I'm kind of curious as to why you commented with a comment that's exactly the same as my answer ?

Comment: I only skimmed your answer and didn't read it in depth. It looked like we were on the same track, hence why I only made a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall rules to see what is being allowed out and what is being allowed in on each of the boxes A and B. Also check to see if there are any intermediate firewalls.

By default, CentOS has a fairly restrictive set of firewall rules and pretty much it only allows ssh and icmp so this would appear to be what you're seeing.

You can see what your [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) firewall rules are with

```
iptables -Lv
```

or just the input chain with

```
iptables -L INPUT -v
```